# Trim the fat from some jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I wrote the following jQuery and it works flawlessly for what I need. But I feel like it can be compressed a little bit or shortened up. I'm kind of a jQuery n00b so sorry if it's obvious...any tips? Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var number = $("#tags-list a").length,
    increment = 1 / number,
    opacity_num = "";

$($('#tags-list a').get().reverse()).each(function(i,el){
    el.id = i + 1;
        opacity_num = el.id / number - increment;
  $(this).css({ opacity: opacity_num });
        $(this).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('tag-hovering');
        });
});
```

});

**note:** the `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` has to stay as a no-conflict wrapper.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do and provide your HTML code? I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the cleanest way I could think of. I took out that reverse because it was kind of ugly, and just swapped the logic around so it wasn't needed.

I also changed `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` to `jQuery(function($) {` because they do the same thing and the second is shorter.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var items = $('#tags-list a'),
      number = items.length;

  items
    .attr('id', function(i){
      return number - i; 
    })
    .css('opacity', function(i) {
      return 1 - ( (i + 1) / number );
    })
    .hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('tag-hovering');
    })
});
```

Comment: this type of leanness was exactly where I was trying to go, but it doesn't work unfortunately. I do love this code thought and will play around with it...I'll let you know if I can get it to work.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Setting values using functions like this was only added in jQuery 1.4, so it won't work if you have an older version.

Comment: I'm using 1.6.2 :)  working with systems that should only go as low as like 1.5.x

Comment: Did you get any JS errors when you tried it out? I just made a very basic page and it worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: No errors, haha. The project I'm working with is complicated to explain and this is just one element of the jQuery I have "firing" when a certain page loads. The code itself actual got the desired result, but conflicted with some other things. I'm going to hack around with it to prevent conflicts.

Comment: It works flawlessly! I had a minor syntax error [facepalm]. Holy s**t man this is awesome. Thanks so much. Everybody +1 this.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should be cleaner to read and will be faster. From what I understand, every time you do the $("#tags-list a"), it's doing a lookup (be it cached or not) as well as firing up a function. The thing is, you can keep references around which allow you to interact directly with a representation of what it originally fetched. Granted, it won't update if you add another 'a' element to #tags-list.. but it'll be faster when you call it on the same data multiple times. Also, $.each is slow on IE.. so you can speed things up a bit by just putting it in a 'for' loop.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var i, el, tagList = $("#tags-list a").get();
    var number = tagList.length,
        increment = 1 / number,
        opacity_num = "";

    var mouseCallback = function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('tag-hovering');
    }
    for(i = tagList.length - 1; i>=0; i++) {
        el = tagList[i];
        el.id = i + 1;
        $(el).css({opacity: el.id / number - increment}).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', mouseCallback);
    }
});
```

Side note. I've rarely been concerned about the actual length of the code - I've always been more concerned as to how readable it is and how well it performs. I can put an entire javascript app in one line, but why bother if it makes it impossible to maintain? If you want to take your code down in length due to load time, run it through a minimizer before making the script live.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I like what you did with the code, but it didn't work correctly with my specific project and logged some errors. On a good note, I agree with you about code. I start out making my code super simple to read and work with. I mean, the code I pasted in is something I could explain to my mom haha. I'm new to Javascripting beyond just the barebones jQuery stuff, so thanks for the help man! I may just compress it like you said.

Comment: No problem - and yeah, I have to deal with people sometimes who make crazy complicated looking code just to drop line lengths.. just doesn't make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
    var number = $("#tags-list a").length;

    $($('#tags-list a').get().reverse()).each(function(i,el){ 
        el.id = i + 1;    
        $(this).attr('id', i+1)
               .css({ opacity: i / number})         
               .bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {           
                   $(this).toggleClass('tag-hovering');         
               }); 
    }); 
});
```

I think I did my math right and cleaned up the opacity calculation. Also removed the extra $(this) casting and just did some chaining

*Edit* need to set the el.Id = i + 1;

Comment: Stole Arnaud's idea to set the id via .attr, rather than el.id = i + 1;

Comment: This is similar to a version I had, but I couldn't get it to work. I tried out the chaining help you suggested though and it worked! thanks man. +1

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var number = $("#tags-list a").length;
  $($('#tags-list a').get().reverse()).each(function(i,el) {
    $(this).attr('id', i+1)
           .css({ opacity: i / number) })
           .bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
             $(this).toggleClass('tag-hovering');
           });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for leaving a lot intact! I tried this and didn't work _exactly_ as I needed. Thanks for the help with .bind though, that works great.